# Add onclick to a tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I am creating a form from javascript. I have to put the onclick on the a tag to call a method when clicked. I am doing like this, but it is not appearing the onclick.

```
function remPass() {
        var log = document.getElementById("login");
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = "post";
        form.action = "";
        log.appendChild(form);
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "text";
        input.name = "username";
        input.className = "username";
        input.placeholder = "Usuario";
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.className = "bt-enter pink";
        a.id = "recordar";
        a.href = "#";
        a.onclick = "remember()"; //Here is the problem
        a.innerHTML = "Recordar contraseña";
        form.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(a);
    }
```

Comment: if remember() is a function, why is it a string?  remove the " " around remember()

Comment: how about adding the "HTML code" instead of creating the form element from scratch?

Comment: @NachoDawg, and the parentheses.

Comment: @Asier GR, if you want to attached onclick event method, setAttribute would be sufficient.

Comment: That was the error, I didn't realise. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need use method, not method's result nor a string

```
a.onclick = remember;
```

And don't forget to create

```
function remember(){
  //some code
}
```

Comment: And what if you want to call a function with some parameter?

Comment: if you write `remember(param1, param2)`, when it's called by click, param1 would be `event` object and second would be undefined. also you can call this function by yourself, passing any parameters you like to

Answer (score 4):

the correct way of doing is like that

```
  a.onclick = remember; //do like that

  var remember = function(){
           //remember logic..
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

the right way is

```
  a.onclick = remember; //without double quotes

  var remember = function(){
           //more code here...
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setAttribute` method to set attributes / properties for the tag while creating it:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("class", "bt-enter pink");
    a.setAttribute("id", "recordar");
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    a.setAttribute("onclick ", "remember();");
    a.innerHTML = "Recordar contraseña";
```

This is the most competent method of creating elements cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should give something of type function not a string:

```
a.onclick = remember;
//....
var remember = function() {
// remember logic
}
```